# wpf drawingcontext slow performance for the first call

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to show the edges of a graph on a WPF. I was hoping to use a class inherited from FrameworkElement to take advantage of DrawingVisual and increase the performance of drawing. The performance is not desirable when I call the public Draw(...) method (25.35 ms). However, when re-sizing the window I call the public Redraw(...) method and the performance is much better (.77 ms). Can anyone help me figure out why? Please note that both of these methods call the private draw(...) method in which the timer is placed to report performance evaluation.

The graph edges are darkRed lines that show the walkable field in [THIS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25206318/Capture.PNG) image.

```
class GraphEdgesHost : FrameworkElement
{
    private Graph _graph;
    private VisualCollection _children;
    private Pen pen;
    public GraphEdgesHost()
    {
        _children = new VisualCollection(this);
        this.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        this._children.Clear();
    }
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return this._children.Count == 0;
    }
    // Provide a required override for the VisualChildrenCount property. 
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return _children.Count; }
    }
    // Provide a required override for the GetVisualChild method. 
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _children.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        return _children[index];
    }

    public void Draw(Graph graph, Func<UV, Point> Transformation, Color color, double thickness)
    {
        this._graph = graph;
        this.pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(color), thickness);
        this.draw(Transformation);
    }
    private void draw(Func<UV, Point> Transformation)
    {
        var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        this._children.Clear();
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            var edges = this._graph.ToEdges();
            foreach (UVLine item in edges)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawLine(this.pen, Transformation(item.Start), Transformation(item.End));
            }
            drawingContext.Close();
        }
        timer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        drawingVisual.Drawing.Freeze();
        this._children.Add(drawingVisual);
    }
    public void Redraw(Func<UV, Point> Transformation)
    {
        this.draw(Transformation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to inspect which method calls actually cause this. This might probably be caused by `ToEdges()` method.

Comment: Thanks for replying! _graph.ToEdges() is called in both Draw and Redraw methods. Thus it seems that it cannot be responsible for the difference in the performance. If I am missing a point, would you be more specific please?